# How to display dynamic data in ListView with ordering

Tags: android, android-listview

What I want to do:

- Display a list of items
- The actual data is coming from an external source and can change
- Each item can have several "columns". E.g. "type", "content", "date"
- The list should e.g. be sortable by "type" and "date".

I thought I might be able to get the desired functionality using a ListView (but maybe also this is a very bad choice?). I have read some stuff about them, but still have some questions. I know that the ListView Displays data which is managed by an Adapter. If I have an ArrayAdapter, does the Listview always display the items in the order of the underlying Array in the Adapter? So to implement sorting, I would have to somehow change the Array in the Adapter? I have read, that you can use SimpleAdapter to have several properties in a row, but the data SimpleAdapter uses seems to be static. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `ListView` will represent depending on how your `ArrayList` or `Vector`(`[]`) is sorted. Now, if you want to have several properties for each row, I would recommend that you create an `Object` of your choice, for instance: `class Person` which takes name, age, address etc etc.
Then create a list which takes `Person` objects. Then in your `getView` of your `ArrayAdapter` that you will override, you can call `Person person = getItem(position);` and now you have a hold of that object in that specific row (position), and can do whatever you want with that `Person` object.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own adapter, and in `getView()` return view that matches your position. For instance if you got data like this:

```
id  name
0   ccc
1   bbb
2   aaa
```

then when you sort by `id` and listview wants row at position 1, you return `1 bbb`. But if you sort by name ascending, and list wants row #2, then you return `0 ccc`. Of course you need to maintain the "mapping", but that's rather trivial.

Comment: so getView gets called by the ListView if it wants to show a row? I have just noticed, that ArrayAdapter has a "sort" method, I guess that can also be useful.

Comment: Yes, alternatively you can sort your source data. Either way will do the trick.